# getchar() reads '10' into '1' and '0' in C

Tags: c

I'm making function working like

Input contains :   “1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10\n”

Function Outputs: “{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}\n”

I want to take a look how getchar() works, so I wrote the function like this:

```
    int c ;

    printf("{");

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
            printf("%c, ", c);
            getchar();

    }
    getchar();
    printf("}\n");
```

and when I put "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10\n”, it comes like:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 
 , }
```

I guess something wrong with buffers inside. Maybe getchar() reads and out character by character so that 10 is considered as 1 and 0 separately?

I looked up some past questions,, but I didn't get it.
Thanks for your insight.

Comment: Yes you're right `getchar()` only reads one character from `stdin`.

Comment: `getchar()` is not `getmultiplechars()`. You get exactly what the name says you get - a single char. *10* is two chars (*0* and *1*).

Comment: Do yourself a favor and [get a good book to learn from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). C is not a good language to learn by trial-and-error, and learning from online resources may not be the best plan, as there is a lot of bad or completely wrong information floating around the interwebs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *input stream* is a sequence of *characters* - not integers, not floats, not strings, just characters.  When you type in something like `1 2 10`, what gets put into the input stream is the character sequence `{'1', ' ', '2', ' ', '1', '0', '\n' }`.  `getchar` simply reads the next character from that character sequence.

Note that in your loop you're calling `getchar` *twice* and throwing away every other input, which is why the trailing `0` doesn't show up.

If you want to *interpret* the character sequence `'1' '0'` as the integer value `10`, then you'll need to either buffer those characters and convert them to an integer value yourself, or use `scanf` with the `%d` conversion specifier:

```
int value;

putchar( '{' );
while ( scanf( "%d", &value ) == 1 )
  printf( "%d, ", value );
printf( "}\n" );
```

Comment: Does 'scanf' return '1' when it finishes reading from the stream?

Comment: @WhiskeyMentalDisturb: `scanf` returns the number of items read and assigned; in this particular case, we're only expecting to read 1 item, so we expect a return value of 1 on success.  If the next non-whitespace character in the input stream is not a decimal digit (say we typed `'a'` instead of `'1'`), then we have a *matching failure*, and in this case `scanf` will return 0.  If there are no characters before end-of-file or there's an error on the input operation, then `scanf` will return EOF.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you are right - *suprisingly* it does what its name says - it inputs character by character. Here `'1'` is a character and `'0'` is another.

Also there are different ways to deal with this - you can form the number on your own from those characters (whenever you see a space you will know that you have seen a number and likely skip mutiple whitespaces) or take a line at a time and get the numbers separated by spaces using `strtok` and then converting them using `strtol`.

Comment: "_suprisingly_ it does what its name says" -- is that the _principle of maximal surprise_? Hmmm, I'll have to incorporate that into my next user interface.